# Helm Error: parse error at invalid syntax

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

How can I escape `()`  in helm template… I tried as below but getting `Error: parse error at yaml:17): invalid syntax`..

At the end I need this output `"{{ (index  . "demo-app-secret") | b64dec }}"`

Here is the yaml.

```
{{- range $externalSecretName, $externalSecret := .Values.externalSecrets }}
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: {{ $.Release.Name }}
spec:
  refreshInterval: 10m
  secretStoreRef:
    name: tf-address-handling-fortanix
    kind: SecretStore
  target:
    name: {{ $.Release.Name }}
    creationPolicy: Owner
    template:
      data:
    {{- range $externalSecret.data }}
        {{ .secretKey }}: "{{ printf "{{ \(index . \"%s\"\) | b64dec }}" .secretKey }}"
    {{- end }}
  data:
    {{- toYaml $externalSecret.data | nindent 4 }}
{{- end }}
```

Here is the values.yaml

```
externalSecrets:
  master-tf-address-handling:
    data:
      - secretKey: xxxxxxxx
        remoteRef:
          key: xxxxx
      - secretKey: yyyy
        remoteRef:
          key: yyyyy
```

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses don't need to be escaped at all, and if you *remove* the backslash escaping before the parentheses then you'll get the output you expect.

```
{{ .secretKey }}: "{{ printf "{{ (index . \"%s\") | b64dec }}" .secretKey }}"
{{/*                             ^              ^
                                  no backslashes                        */}}
```

If you run this through `helm template`, you'll get a second error.  The output string you get has unescaped double-quotes inside a double-quoted string

```yaml
xxxxxxxx: "{{ (index . "xxxxxxxx") | b64dec }}"
#         ^            ^        ^             ^
#                too many double quotes
```

To fix this you need extra backslashes in the output

```yaml
xxxxxxxx: "{{ (index . \"xxxxxxxx\") | b64dec }}"
#                      ^         ^
#                 add these backslashes
```

and to get that you need an additional double backslash inside the template

```
{{ .secretKey }}: "{{ printf "{{ (index . \\\"%s\\\") | b64dec }}" .secretKey }}"
{{/*                                      ^^    ^^
                                    add these backslashes                   */}}
```

Comment: it did not work.. I tried as you suggested like below but this time I am getting `error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 14: did not find expected key`



`{{ .secretKey }}: "{{ printf "{{ (index . \"%s\") | b64dec }}" .secretKey }}"`

Comment: Putting the example in a little broader context might help.  I was able to run this fragment via `helm template --debug` and it output the correct string (and then a long error message), that error sounds like something's gone wrong with the final YAML output but not necessarily the templating syntax _per se_.

Comment: I correspondingly expanded the answer.  Of note, using the [mcve] in the question, I can run `helm template` over it with the described fixes without Helm errors.

Comment: @When I add three backslahes, I see extra / in the output where I dont need this
`"{{ (index . \"xxxxxxxxxx\") | b64dec }}"`

Comment: You _do_ need that, or else it's not valid YAML.  You could also change the outer double quotes to single quotes (but one form of quote or the other is required).